# How to retrieve WP_Object that is inside an array of another array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am building a WordPress website that uses a custom AJAX filter that is linked to my Custom categories.

This is my function **ajax-filter.php**:

```
   function filter() {

 $uid = get_current_user_id();
 $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;
 $customer_account  = get_field('customer_account', 'user_'.$uid );



   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'cpt',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'orderby' => 'date',
     'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'customer',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => $customer_account,
       )
     )
   );

       $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
       $results = array();


               if (!empty($the_query->posts))
               {
                   foreach ($the_query->posts as $post)
                   {
                       $id = $post->ID;
                       array_push($results, array(
                           'id' => $id,
                           'title' => get_field('e_detail_title', $id),
                           'tax' => get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'type', $id ),

                       ));
                   }
               }
                  wp_reset_postdata();

          $someJSON = json_encode($results);
          // Convert JSON string to Object
          $someObject = json_decode($someJSON);

          foreach($someObject as $key => $value) {
                 echo $value->title;

                }
      die;
    }
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter' );
```

My question is:

How can i use my data from *tax* to *term-id* in the way that i use in my **ajax-filter.php?** to use my data **($value->title)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
          [title] => title
          [tax] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Term Object
                        (
                            [term_id] => 54
)

                )

        )
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do. Your ajax-filter.php code doesn't make a lot of sense. You're looping through `$the_query`, which hasn't been made in your function or retrieved from anywhere. Then you're pushing values into an array, encoding it into JSON, immediately *de*coding it, then looping through and echoing a property that doesn't exist. Not to mention the values you're putting in are *term* objects into a *tax* field. Also `filter()` is a dangerously generic name for a function (and doesn't appear to describe what you're doing). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JacobPeattie i updated the code. i forgot to place that line in.

Comment: That's great but you're still going to have to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie
 
When i use my data as `$value->title;` i get my title. but what i want is from within my tax array to show the id of my tax. it would be something like this `$value->tax->term_id;`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an object inside an array. To retrieve the data from `term_id`, you can use:

```
$value[0]['tax'][0]->term_id
```

Notice that the first 3 steps are arrays, and then there is a `WP_Object`, which has an array inside.

### Breaking Down the Code

```
$value                          - returns the entire array
$value[0]                       - returns the first element of the array
$value[0]['tax']                - returns the `tax` element and all of its contents
$value[0]['tax'][0]             - returns the first element of `tax`
$value[0]['tax'][0]->term_id    - points to the term id inside the above
```

### UPDATE

You don't need to use `json_encode` or `json_decode`. Simply use a foreach to output the content:

```
foreach( $results as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['tax']->term_id;
}
```

You might also want to use `$value['tax'][0]->term_id` if there are multiple terms inside the tax.

Comment: When i put this code in, nothing happens.

Comment: `echo $value[0]['tax'][0]->term_id;`

Comment: @Dionoh Does `$value[0]['tax'][0]['term_id']` work? When you encode and decode from json (why are you doing this) you're turning everything into an array.

Comment: Not working. What would you do instead of encode and decode?

Comment: I used  `echo '<pre>';
     print_r($value);
       echo '</pre>';`

Comment: @JackJohansson not working again

Comment: @JackJohansson maybe because i use acf custom fields that it's not working?